# Undesirable horizontal spacing in the flalign environment

Tags: spacing, align

I am trying to create two columns of text/mathematical expressions that are aligned to the left. In the `flalign` environment, the horizontal spacing between the two columns works well when the second column has a sufficient amount of text. However, in the case that the second column has minimal text, the horizontal spacing is too large. I have included a MWE of this below. How can I reduce the horizontal spacing?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\section*{Notation}
\begin{flalign*}
&\text{E} &&\text{Short example} \ \alpha \\
&\text{G} &&\text{Slightly longer example} \ \beta\\
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `fl` in `flalign` stands for  **Full Length** so the expression is  the full width of the text block, and you get the expected result

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't know that. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that it's important to you to have the first column of the two-column `flalign*` material start at the left-hand edge of the text block. To shift the second column to the *left* (and hence to create some whitespace to the right of the second column), one can insert pairs of `&&` to the far right of (say) the first row. For instance, the first, second, and third such pairs of `&&` reduce the space between the two columns by one half, two thirds, and three quarters, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,hmargin=3cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section*{Notation}

\begin{flalign*}
&\text{E} &&\text{Short example} \ \alpha \\
&\text{G} &&\text{Slightly longer example} \ \beta 
\end{flalign*}
\begin{flalign*}
&\text{E} &&\text{Short example} \ \alpha && \\ % 1 pair of '&&'
&\text{G} &&\text{Slightly longer example} \ \beta 
\end{flalign*}
\begin{flalign*}
&\text{E} &&\text{Short example} \ \alpha &&&& \\ % 2 pairs of '&&'
&\text{G} &&\text{Slightly longer example} \ \beta 
\end{flalign*}
\begin{flalign*}
&\text{E} &&\text{Short example} \ \alpha &&&&&& \\ % 3 pairs of '&&'
&\text{G} &&\text{Slightly longer example} \ \beta 
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear to me your intention with `flalign`. Description of some abbreviations or variables as can be concluded from section titles? For this seems to be use of some table, for example designed by `tabularx`, more appropriate tool:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=3cm,
            vmargin={2.5cm,3cm}
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\section*{Notation}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{\qquad} L}
E   &   Short example $\alpha$              \\
G   &   Slightly longer example $\beta$     \\
H   &   Very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very long description
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

by which you can get:

[image]